# Why am I getting warning 'C6386' Buffer overrun while writing to 'ptr'?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

`Variable 'size' is 10 in this example. If I were to hardcode 10 in place of 'int(size)' the overrun warning goes away. Any suggestions/reasoning why this is occurring? I want to allocate 80 bytes for my pointer, each of the allocated values being a timestep from the given timespan.

Thank you!

```
int main() {
    const double h = 0.1;
    const double tspan[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    const double size =round(tspan[1] / h);
    double *ptr = (double*)malloc(int(size) * sizeof(double));

    if (!ptr) {
        cout << "Memory Allocation Failed";
        exit(1);
    }

    double j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ptr[i] = j;
            
        //cout << j << '\n';
        j++;
    }

    cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << *(ptr + i) << endl;
        //cout << i << '\n';
    }
    
    
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried dereferencing the pointer and making sure it isn't NULL. I have also printed out the result. The result being a pointer that counts 0-9. `

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++ if you want a bit easier life.

Comment: Squelching that compiler warning about passing a non-integral type value to `malloc` for the size by hard-converting `size` to a temporary `int` isn't looking like such a hot idea right about now. Warnings are nearly always logical errors, *especially* for people new to the language.

Comment: Thank you for all the quick responses! 
I need the pointer to store data of type double. The 'size' variable is rounded to remove the chance of an extra iteration. Granted, it could round up, but safe to say it isn't doing that in this case.

Comment: @KennethCarnemolla You should not be using floating point functions for integer-based problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addedum to what 273K has answered, you can solve this problem by having `size` as an `int` variable. If we work with size as n int all the time, we don't have the possibility of being bitten by floating point issues when comparing in loop tests.

Let's floor the result of that division and cast to `int`.

```
int main() {
    const double h = 0.1;
    const double tspan[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    const int size = static_cast<int>(std::floor(tspan[1] / h));
    double *ptr = (double*)malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    if (!ptr) {
        cout << "Memory Allocation Failed";
        exit(1);
    }

    double j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ptr[i] = j;
            
        //cout << j << '\n';
        j++;
    }

    cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << *(ptr + i) << endl;
        //cout << i << '\n';
    }
    
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Somewhat better, let's use new and delete instead of malloc and free.

```
int main() {
    const double h = 0.1;
    const double tspan[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    const int size = static_cast<int>(std::floor(tspan[1] / h));
    double *ptr = new double[size];

    if (!ptr) {
        std::cout << "Memory Allocation Failed";
        exit(1);
    }

    double j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ptr[i] = j;
            
        //std::cout << j << '\n';
        j++;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << *(ptr + i) << std::endl;
        //cout << i << '\n';
    }
    
    delete[] ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Better still, use `std::vector`. We don't need to worry about managing the memory ourselves, and we can use smarter for loops that let the vector take care of bounds checking.

```
int main() {
    const double h = 0.1;
    const double tspan[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    const int size = static_cast<int>(std::floor(tspan[1] / h));
    std::vector<double> vec(size);

    double j = 0;
    for (auto &x : vec) {
        x = j;
            
        //std::cout << j << '\n';
        j++;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto x : vec) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        //std::cout << i << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all! The vector approach is smooth. 
I am picking up C++ for the first time in many years. I have much learning to do!

Answer (score 3):

`double size` can be `10.1`, the condition `i < 10.1` does not terminate the loop if `i` is 10, the allocated buffer size is `int(10.1)`, that is 10, `ptr[10]` causes the buffer overrun.

Comment: When I print counter i in the ptr[i]=j for loop it counts 0-9, as we would expect. 

Also if I change my const doubles to const int, the same issue occurs

Answer (score 0):

`round()` rounds to the nearest integer number. If anything, you should use `ceil()` to round **up**.